# C++ string.replace generates "No matching function for call" error

Tags: c++, string, class, object

Can anyone tell me why this piece of code generates the "No matching function for call" error? I believe that the syntax is correct, I really have no idea why it does not work. I want to replace an occurence of {{some_key}} in Template_ with the matching value of some_key in unordered_map passed to function.

```
std::string View::Render(const std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> &model) const {

    for(int i = 0; i < this->Template_.length(); ++i){
        if(this->Template_[i] == '{' && this->Template_[i+1] == '{'){

            int PositionBegin = i;
            std::string Key = FindKey();

            if(Key.length() > 0) {
                std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator Found = model.find(Key);
                if (Found != model.end())
                    this->Template_.replace(PositionBegin, Key.length()+4, Found->second);
            }
        }
    }

    return this->Template_;
}
```

View class looks as simple as this:

```
class View {
public:
    View(const std::string &Template);
    std::string Render(const std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> &model) const;
    std::string Template_;
};
```

The full error is:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::replace(int&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::size_type, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&) const’ this->Template_.replace(PositionBegin, Key.length()+4, Found->second);
```

Comment: Can provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is defined as

```
std::string View::Render(const std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> &model) const
```

Since it is `const` that means you cannot modify any of the the class members.  `replace` would modify `Template_` so you cannot call it.

You have two ways to fix this.  You can get rid of the `const` on the function if you want to be able to manipulate `Template` or you can declare `Template_` as `mutable` so it can be modified.

Comment: Or use a local variable initialized to `Template_` and modify and return that.

Comment: Thank you. I completely forgot about it. It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by attempting to modify a member variable of a `const` object.

The member function is a `const` member function.  Hence, `this->Template_` is also a `const` object. You are trying to modify `this->Template_` by using

```
this->Template_.replace(PositionBegin, Key.length()+4, Found->second);
```

If your program logic requires you to modify `this->Template_` in a `const` member function, you'll have to qualify it with `mutable`.